# The controllers namespace must start with your application namespace: App</error >

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, voyager

I found this error when wanting to publish my namespace in the file voyager.php with the instruction, `php artisan voyager:controllers

route:

[image]

voyager.php

```
'controllers' => [
    'namespace' => 'TCG\\Voyager\\Http\\Controllers',
    'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Voyager',
],
```

error message:

```
**The controllers namespace must start with your application namespace: App</error>**
```

I have applied these commands

```
composer dumpautoload
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
composer update
```

install and uninstall voyager

I use the version of laravel 5.5

Also insert the provider
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,

Comment: Inside config/voyager.php change to this: 'controllers' => [
    'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Voyager',
],

Comment: Yes, but that was not the problem, my problem apparently was the order of the installation, although I work with branches with bitbucket, and when doing a merge it was solved, although I do not know what the solution was, if the installation order or the merge

Answer (score 3):

Change

`'namespace' => 'TCG\\Voyager\\Http\\Controllers',`

To

`'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Voyager',`

For detail visit [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1420), [GitHub Issue 2](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1270)

Answer (score 3):

Please try to following

1. php artisan optimize
2. php artisan voyager:controllers

You will be success.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own Controller by extending Voyager's Controllers. To do it, first define your controller Namespace at 
`config/voyager.php` :

```
    'controllers' => [
        'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Voyager',
    ],
```

then run `php artisan voyager:controllers`, voyager will now use the child controllers which will be created at

`App/Http/Controllers/Voyager`

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the cache after change the namespace

```
php artisan config:cache
```